# Not set value 0xxxxxx for input text - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input :

```
<input type="text"/>
```

I set value for input text as :

```
$('#input-text').val(012345);
```

But it show : "12345" . Where is my zero ?

Comment: make it a string `$('#input-text').val('012345')` or add a leading string 0

Comment: Try this:

$('#input-text').val("012345");
// Now 012345 is a string

Comment: I got it. Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`012345` is turned into `12345`. Leading zeroes are insignificant (they cannot be used for anything) and are therefore removed when the number is parsed by the Javascript engine.

If you want the preceding zero to stay then you must turn it into a string:

```
$('#input-text').val("012345");
```

Comment: Yep. I got it. Thank you !